# Web API sending an object to the Controller via Java Script

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm using **Angular/C# Web** API.

In my JavaScript **service** I have the following.

```
invoicesForCustomer = $http.get('/api/Customer/GetInvoicesForCustomer',
{params:element} );
```

In the Web API Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public InvoiceListModel GetInvoicesForCustomer(InvoiceListOptionsModel element)
```

but this element object is always null. I tried this for a single parameter and it worked. 
Any help on sending an object via querystring to Web API controller..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Try changing `[HttpGet]` to `[HttpPost]`. Also your

```
$http({
    url: "/api/Customer/GetInvoicesForCustomer", 
    method: "GET", ---> This should be post too
    data: {'element': element}
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

from your api definition it seems you need it as data and not as a query params

```
$http({
    url: "/api/Customer/GetInvoicesForCustomer", 
    method: "GET",
    data: {'element': element}
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
invoicesForCustomer = $http.get('/api/Customer/GetInvoicesForCustomer', {params:element} );
```

**to**

```
invoicesForCustomer = $http.get('/api/Customer/GetInvoicesForCustomer', {"element":element} );
```

**Update : Please try following way to call API**

```
$http({
    url: "/api/Customer/GetInvoicesForCustomer", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {element: element}
 });
```

Comment: what error you get in console..?and there are multiple ways to call this get.pleas see the updated answer

Comment: Updated code threw an exception in console and it didn't come to the controller.
"GET http://localhost:8080/KtvCustomer/api/Customer/GetInvoicesForCustomer?eleme…owAll%22:false%7D,%22SearchString%22:null,%22SortOn%22:4,%22SortBy%22:1%7D 404 (Not Found)"

But previous came to the controller with element as null.

Comment: it might be because i forget to add "/" infront of "api/custo.."